# ajax keeps returning my main webpage instead of words in output

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem with my ajax call, ive been searching here and cant find a answer to.
here is what happened the script worked great one second then when i logged in to use it again it just shows me my main index page any time i put http:// inside the text area here is the code.

```
    function is_valid_url() 

var ajaxRequest;
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('output');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;

        }

    }

    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;


    var queryString = "?text=" + text;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "textscraper.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 

  }
```

here is the html

```
<textarea id="text" onkeyup="is_valid_url()" placeholder="What do you think?" class="posttext">
</textarea>
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: a little more clerification it shows the text ok but the minute http:// is put in it shows my main webaddress page instead of text.

Comment: I think you'd want to use onchange instead of onkeyup.

Comment: no onkeyup so it checks to clarify the difference between the regular words and the urls trid onchange and that does nothing until you click outside the textarea and it repeats the same problem with onchange as well

Comment: besides i took all the coding for url check out of my php script and alls it is doing is echo back the words.

Comment: and i just tried clearing my browser history and still got the same out put.

Comment: ok just learned somethin new if i put my url in it works but if i put in a different url it doesnt any ideas?